# Request take too many times

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know which request (and which index) will be the best to do that. I Use Symfony. But for this request I used normal SQL.
I did tables with doctrine.

I would like to have the asset of each Client.

I have around

Tables:

```
Client ~ 15 000 rows ->  Index : foreign key,id, reference, 
Invoice ~ 750 000 rows -> Index : foreign key,id, reference, 
Invoice_line ~ 4 000 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, qty, price, reference, 
"credit_note" ~ 40 000 rows -> Index : foreign key,id, reference, 
"credit_note_line" ~ 61 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, id, qty, price, reference, 
Product ~ 75 000 rows -> Index : foreign key, id, reference,
```

the line represent one product with is price and quantity

Asset for one Client = Total Client's Invoices - Total  Client's Credit Notes

So I did this request:

```
SELECT
    a1.reference,
    a1.id,
    SUM(a1.balance) AS "asset"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c2.reference,
        c2.id,
        SUM(il.quantity * il.unit_price) AS "balance"
    FROM CLIENT AS
        c2
    INNER JOIN invoice AS i
    ON
        i.client_id = c2.id
    INNER JOIN invoice_line AS il
    ON
        i.id = il.invoice_id
GROUP BY
    c2.reference
UNION ALL
SELECT
    c1.reference,
    c1.id,
    - SUM(cnl.quantity * cnl.unit_price) AS "balance"
FROM CLIENT AS
    c1
INNER JOIN credit_note AS cn
ON
    cn.client_id = c1.id
INNER JOIN credit_note_line AS cnl
ON
    cn.id = cnl.credit_note_id
GROUP BY
    c1.reference
) AS a1
GROUP BY
    reference
ORDER BY
    `asset`
DESC
```

It give me the right answer but it's very long. How can I reduce the request time?
I would like also the asset for N-1 so I have to do this request twice and it take too much time.

Comment: Do some work to figure out what is taking time?  For instance, you have two subqueries in the `union`.  Does one take a long time?

Comment: I did the test and the first request in the union is taking 30sec the second one 2 sec. So is the first one. But I don't know what to do. I have already indexed. + Maybe i can have a better request to do : Total invoices - total credit note for each client. And have 1 for this year and an other one for n-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT c.reference, MIN(c.id) as id,
       SUM(il.quantity * il.unit_price) AS asset
FROM CLIENT c JOIN
     invoice i
     ON i.client_id = c.id
     invoice_line il
     ON i.id = il.invoice_id
GROUP BY c.reference;
```

The only way to speed this query is with indexes on the `JOIN` columns.  I would recommend covering indexes:

- `invoice_line(invoice_id, quantity, unit_price)`
- `invoice(client_id, id)`
- `client(reference, id)`

Comment: Is much better ! Thank you :) 

I had to change tour SQL synthax : 

`SELECT c.reference, MIN(c.id) as id
FROM CLIENT c JOIN
     invoice i
     ON i.client_id = c.id
     JOIN
     invoice_line as il
     ON il.invoice_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.reference`

But In order to have the year N-1 how can I Do ? I need to make more indexes on date but i must do 2 request ?

Comment: I did 2 times the request and now (I indexed dates field) i takes only 3-4 seconds instead of 100... Really cool. Thank you